# .h5 model fails to load on PC but loads on Colab

Tags: tensorflow, h5py

I'm trying to load my trained model on PC using the code

```
reloaded_model = load_model('./my_model.h5',custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})
```

There are no errors while loading on colab notebook. I was also running on PC a day ago but now its showing an error:

```
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'KerasLayer' using config={'name': 'keras_layer_2', 'trainable': False, 'dtype': 'float32', 'handle': 'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_130_224/classification/5'}.

Exception encountered: Trying to load a model of incompatible/unknown type. 'C:\Users\muham\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\2c858e9d5fe42a1181c58c70d67244f7619f2ab2' contains neither 'saved_model.pb' nor 'saved_model.pbtxt'.
```

I tried to search for the error but got no help.